# How to Save Condition Case or IF to variabel in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case, conditional-statements

How to save condition case or if to variabel?
so i dont need write same condition again for next.

this is mysql syntax :

```
SELECT  v_jadwal_personal.ID_karyawan,
                        v_jadwal_personal.nik_karyawan,
(CASE WHEN
    (SELECT wkt_masuk FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) < 0
THEN
    ADDTIME(jam_masuk,(SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja))
WHEN
    (SELECT wkt_masuk FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) >= 0
THEN
    ADDTIME(jam_masuk,(SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus 
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja))
END) AS jammasuk,
(CASE WHEN
    (SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) < 0
THEN
    ADDTIME(jam_pulang,(SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja))
WHEN
    (SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) >= 0
THEN
    ADDTIME(jam_pulang,(SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus 
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja))
END) AS jampulang,
                        v_jadwal_personal.totaljam,
                        v_tmp_history_absensi.waktu_masuk,
                        v_tmp_history_absensi.waktu_pulang,
                        v_tmp_history_absensi.hari_kerja,
                        v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja,
                        v_tmp_history_absensi.nama_karyawan,
                        TIMEDIFF(waktu_pulang,waktu_masuk) AS totaljamkerja,
                        (CASE WHEN
    (SELECT wkt_masuk FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) < 0
THEN
    TIMEDIFF(waktu_masuk,(ADDTIME(jam_masuk,(SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja))))
WHEN
    (SELECT wkt_masuk FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) >= 0
THEN
    TIMEDIFF(waktu_masuk,(ADDTIME(jam_masuk,(SELECT wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus 
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja))))
END)  AS terlambat,
                        TIMEDIFF(jam_pulang,waktu_pulang) as lebihan,
(SELECT wkt_masuk FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
                    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) AS teswaktu                    
FROM v_jadwal_personal JOIN v_tmp_history_absensi
                        ON v_tmp_history_absensi.ID_karyawan = v_jadwal_personal.ID_karyawan
                        AND v_tmp_history_absensi.hari_kerja = v_jadwal_personal.nama_hari
                        WHERE v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23'
                        AND v_jadwal_personal.ID_karyawan=1
```

so, i think too many case condition and thats have same condition..

Comment: thats very dirty code.  YOu should clean it up

Comment: @Gergo, thank u for ur editing :)
i'm new in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @fallenreaper, yeah, that's why i'm ask in here :)
hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: can someone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a subquery as one of the tables:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM table this
        JOIN table that ON condition
        JOIN
            (
                SELECT long_computation AS result
                    FROM table
                    WHERE condition
            ) s ON condition
    WHERE condition
```

Then you can use s.result.

An alternative is to use a view, but that's only valid if the bit to factorise is always the same.

Comment: u mean i put case condition on subquery and then join?

Comment: You can probably use `(SELECT wkt_masuk, wkt_plg FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja)` so you have easy access to wkt_masuk and wkt_plg. Same for the other one.

Comment: Actually, you probably need to move at least part of the condition to the JOIN condition, but I'm too lazy to try to decode the whole SQL and find out exactly what you should do :-)

Comment: but in there i have some condition like : **SELECT wkt_masuk FROM d_jamkerja_khusus
    WHERE tgl_krj BETWEEN '2014-05-14' AND '2014-05-23' AND tgl_krj=v_tmp_history_absensi.tgl_kerja) < 0**

Comment: The condition itself you leave in the `CASE WHEN` (as there are different cases...), but you can simplify them like this `CASE WHEN s.wkt_masuk<0`...

Comment: thank you for ur ateention, now i get my code is not too long :) i think some function ADDTIME is same, so i make it one
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @de_, please post your own answer if you have solved your own problem. Don't [edit another person's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5169358).

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry, i try on answer but can't post :)
btw, thats not good code to solved with join, because the date range can't display all :/